# Проблемы с Jackson и ResultSet JAVA

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jackson

У меня spring mvc.
Я хожу в базу (PostgreSQL) вот так вот : select array_to_json(array_agg(t1)) from shops as t1

Потом я наивно надеюсь в контроллере сделать return прямо этого ResultSet, т.к он по факту уже JSON. Но Jackson мне говорит - "Не сегодня" и мы дружно падаем вот с таким Exception.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.postgresql.jdbc2.TimestampUtils]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.postgresql.jdbc2.TimestampUtils and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet["statement"]->org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement["connection"]->org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection["timestampUtils"])
org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:295)
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:272)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Когда я отключил падение при пустых бинах я пожалел). Там было много разного и не понятного, но явно не ответ в формате JSON. Как дальше жить?

Comment: Вы должны  сделать сериализатор для `org.postgresql.jdbc2.TimestampUtils` ибо `Jackson` хз как его переводить в `json` формат (о чем и говорит ошибка - "я не знаю как это преобразовать в `json`").
P.S Не изобретайте велосипед. Используйте уже готовое для общения с базой - Hibernate, Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Так этож и есть уже JSON типо). Выглядит - хз как переводить JSON в JSON:)? Я понял. А как мне поможет hibernate?

Comment: Jackson переводит объекты в json, а вы ему подсовываете строку, а не объект. Код контроллера напишите.

Comment: @ДимаГуманов ему объект нужен, а не строка.